# Casting a word to a longword in C

Tags: c, memory-alignment

When we cast an `unsigned int` to an `unsigned long` in C (for this example, we can assume that unsigned ints are 32bit long and unsigned longs are 64 bits long), will the an expression using the resulting value be properly aligned with an 8-byte boundary?

```
unsigned int i  = 8;
if ((unsigned long)i == 8) // <--- is (unsigned long)i aligned properly?
{
 // do something
}
```

If initially `i` is aligned with a 4-byte boundary, then assuming that the address of the casted value does not change, `(unsigned long) i` is not necessarily aligned with an 8-byte boundary, although its length is 8 bytes. On the other hand, is it safe to assume that the compiler will allocate some new stack location (temporary, maybe?) for the result of the cast and thus properly align it at some extra cost?

Comment: `(unsigned long)i` does not exists in memory, it has no location in memory, it is a rvalue. `it safe to assume that the compiler will allocate some new stack` - no, the compiler will not allocate anything. The question "is (unsigned long)i aligned?" makes no sense. `(unsigned long)i` doesn't have any memory address. This is almost like asking about "is `(unsigned long)42` aligned?".

Comment: There is a fundamental assumption here that values will be in memory. That mental model is certainly taught in textbooks, so I don't blame you. But it is not realistic. That makes the question harder to answer because it is based on an incorrect premise.